# Google Custom search api discrepancy in result

Tags: ruby, search, google-api-ruby-client

I am first trying the standard web search, image below, which returns **476** results

[image]

I have the custom [Google ruby api client](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client) and have the [custom search engine](https://www.google.com/cse/all) and api key setup.

This is my query

```
client = Google::APIClient.new(application_name: 'Foo',
                                     application_version: 1,
                                     :authorization => nil)
        search = client.discovered_api('customsearch')
        result = client.execute(
            search.cse.list,
            'key' => 'xxxxx.xxxx_xxxxx_mykey',
            'q' => 'chateau palmer',
            'siteSearch' => 'nytimes.com',
            'siteSearchFilter' => 'i',
            'cx' => 'my_custom_Search key'
        )
        total =  result.data.queries.request.collect {|i| i['totalResults']}
```

The result i get are completely different in count, what can be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20182732/1336988) and by [Google.](https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/70392?hl=en)

> your results are unlikely to match those returned by Google Web
>   Search, for several reasons:
>
> - Even if a custom search engine is configured to search the entire web,
>     it’s designed to emphasize results from your own sites.
> - Your custom search engine doesn’t include Google Web Search features such as
>     Oneboxes, real-time results, universal search, social feaures, or
>     personalized results.
> - If your custom search engine includes more than
>     ten sites, the results may be from a subset of our index and may
>     differ from the results of a 'site:' search on Google.com.

Also, of other note, there are a great deal of flags that you can set such as location and language that the web version determines which have to be set in your code when using the API.