# Is it possible to use google custom search features without creating one's own website?

Tags: python, google-chrome

I would like to write a program that loops through about 7000 entries of a certain keyword and then searches Google for that keyword. Then for each keyword, I would like to return the number of search results. Finally, I would like to populate a `pandas` dataframe like structure with keyword1, no_results1, keyword2, no_results2, ..., keywordn, no_resultsn.

I am proficient with `python` and use of web scraping tools like `BeautifulSoup` and `selenium`. However, I am also aware that it is not necessarily legal or conforming to Google's terms and conditions to use their search engine willy nilly.

Therefore, I looked into the google `JSON API` which appears to be somewhat suited to my usage. However, the self-proclaimed goal of [this API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/) is as follows:

> Google Custom Search enables you to create a search engine for your
>   website, your blog, or a collection of websites. You can configure
>   your engine to search both web pages and images. You can fine-tune the
>   ranking, add your own promotions and customize the look and feel of
>   the search results. You can monetize the search by connecting your
>   engine to your Google AdSense account.

Which is not quite what I need. Is it possible/legal to use google custom search features without creating one's own website?

Comment: If you think this question should be closed, would you please indicate why so that I can improve it. Thanks

Comment: Each question in SO should have one question in it, not two. Even so, the two questions you have asked are far too broad to provide any meaningful answer without guiding you through the entire process.

Comment: It's a REST API, so the answer to your question is "Yes, you can use it without creating a website". If you need to know more than that, search "How to poll REST API with Python".

Comment: @Ethan Field... doing some reading now. Have you ever used it without creating a website?

Comment: I've never used this API before, but I have used Python to interact with REST APIs before. There is also a question right here on SO for it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17301938/making-a-request-to-a-restful-api-using-python

Comment: Actually I found out that custom search returns inferior results than a regular google search https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20182667/google-api-returning-different-results-than-website. This kind of makes it obsolete for my use case

Comment: Are you planning on using the googleapiclient module to accomplish the keyword searching?

Comment: How is googleapiclient different from the Custom Search Engine?

Comment: Here is the difference:  https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/70392?hl=en